# handlebar js custom helper for else if

Tags: handlebars.js

I have started using Handlebars.js. It seems that there is no built in conditionals like else if.
I want to have something like this

```
{{#if type.one }}
     do something ... IF
{{else if type.two}}
     do something ... ELSE IF
{{else}}
     do something ... ELSE
{{/if}}
```

But this doesn't work. How do I do ELSE IF with handlebars? Is writing a custom helper is the only option ?  If yes then please provide some pointers to write this  helper.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Handlebars 3.0 the syntax described by OP does work out of the box! See: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/892 for more information.

*Note:
For Ember, since version 1.10 and up this does work too. See also:
http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_chained-else-blocks*

Answer (score 21):

You can't do this with a custom helper as Handlebars if-ish helpers only understand two parts: the "if" part and the "else" part. You can nest things though:

```
{{#if type.one}}
    do something ... IF
{{else}}
    {{#if type.two}}
        do something ... ELSE IF
    {{else}}
        {{#if type.three}}
            ...
        {{else}}
            ...
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

That sort of thing will get nasty fast so you probably don't want to do that. A better approach would (as usual with Handlebars) be to push the logic into your JavaScript so that at most one of `type.one`, `type.two`, `type.three`, ... would be true; then you could:

```
{{#if type.one}}
    ...
{{/if}}
{{#if type.two}}
    ...
{{/if}}
{{#if type.three}}
    ...
{{/if}}
```

If you have a lot of options for `type` or if the bodies in your `{{#if}}`s are complicated, you could switch to partials. You'd have to add a custom helper to build a partial name based on a template variable though; something like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('show_type', function(type) {
    var types = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    var partial;
    for(var i = 0; i < types.length; ++i) {
        if(!type[types[i]])
            continue;
        partial = '_partial_' + types[i];
        break;
    }
    if(partial)
        return Handlebars.partials[name](this);
    else
        return '';
});
```

and then, assuming your partials are all registered and consistently named, you could say:

```
{{show_type type}}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using ember like framework,

```
{{#if isAtWork}}
     Ship that code!
{{else if isReading}}
      You can finish War and Peace eventually...
{{/if}}
```

link : http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/templates/conditionals/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
{{#if type.one}}
  ...
{{else}} {{#if type.two}}
  ...
{{else}} {{#if type.three}}
  ...
{{else}}
  ...
{{/if}}{{/if}}{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a switch behaviour, you might be interested in [Dan Harper's helpers](https://github.com/danharper/Handlebars-Helpers), you will be able to do something like :

```
{{#is type 1}}
    <p>Do something when 1.</p>
{{else}}{{#is type 2}}
    <p>Do something when 2.</p>
{{else}}{{#is type 3}}
    <p>Do something when 3.</p>
{{/is}}{{/is}}{{/is}}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/199jdzn2/).

Answer (score 0):

The exact syntax that the OP has written will work in Ember Canary today with the 
`ember-htmlbars-inline-if-helper` feature flag enabled.